# No SSO integration as your application does not populate the Universal Navigation Link

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am integrating Google Apps Marketplace SDK for my application.

In the Extensions section i have selected "Universal navigation extension" and entered link like "http://spring-bok.com".

After published my application in GAM i am getting a reply mail from esupport@google.com saying that "No SSO integration as your application does not populate the Universal Navigation Link."

How do i activate UNL,Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Google API project for your app before it can make any API calls, so this usually the first step in developing a MArketPlace app.

Select the services to use, go to Google Developers Console and enable the Google Apps MarketPlace SDK , and enable the APIs or SDKs for any other services that your app requires.The app can only access Google services if you enable them.

Check out the Official Google Documentation on how to set up our project: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/preparing